# Skype equivalent + supporting SDK(Software Development Kit) which enables writing service recording calls

Tags: communication, skype, sdk

I look for equivalent of Skype which supports telephony(you can call to telephone number, for instance +48 22 432 323) and has SDK(Software Development Kit) which enables writing plugins or services which record calls.

As far as I know Skype does not have SDK which enables this. I look for SDK for **.NET** or Java.

The system is: Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: If you're only looking to make calls programmatically you may as well sign up for a SIP account at any provider and interact with that, or install a PABX such as Asterisk (free as in freedom+beer).

Answer (score 1):

**Lync** is Windows software manufactured by the same company which now runs Skype. It can call/accept external phone numbers, recording is built into the default client and it has `SDK` allowing to extend the default client or build new ones, e.g. kiosk

- [TechNet: Technical diagrams for Lync Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn594589.aspx)
- [TechNet: New Enterprise Voice features in Lync Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398964.aspx)
- [Office development > Lync > Lync 2013 > Lync 2013 SDK documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933180(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: On that I found: "You cannot record with the Lync SDK, but you can record calls from a UCMA endpoint. You can create a conference that includes the UCMA endpoint and the other Lync clients, and then record the conference with the UCMA endpoint."

Comment: https://ucwa.lync.com/about/about-ucwa says: "_Unified Communications Web API...While using standard web technologies such as HTTP, HTML, CSS, JSON, and JavaScript. UCWA is language-agnostic and one can choose any programming language to code against it. UCWA is currently available only to customers who have Lync on-premises_". I can't say more about this technology except that it is the platform that Microsoft offers to companies to solve their telephony needs (ICT was using the Lync service at my 2 previous jobs). Contact their sales/support to verify if it's what you need